# Constant not staying constant?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, p5.js

I made a code with the intention of having a square appear where the mouse is pressed down, stay in that spot despite mouse movement and not disappear when the mouse it released.

THIS IS P5.JS ! https://p5js.org/reference/

Instead, the square follows the mouse until it is released then it disappears!

I believe that my code keeps declaring a new constant and deleting the old one every time the shoot() function is run.

```
var clocker = 0;// NOT YET USED

var player = {
    x:400,
    y:400,
};

function shoot(x1, y1, x2, y2, speed, range, power, playerDirection){

    var bulletAlive = true;
    var bulletDamage = power;
    const startX = x1;
    const startY = y1;
    const destX = x2;
    const destY = y2;
    var bulletX = startX;
    var bulletY = startY;

    if(bulletAlive){
      fill(0,100,200);
      rect(destX-12.5,destY-12.5,25,25);
    };


};

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);
}

function draw() {

    background(204,204,204);

    if(mouseIsPressed){
      shoot(player.x,player.y,mouseX,mouseY,2,100,0,"right");
    }

}
```

Perhaps I am using const wrong. If so how should I use it? How can I make it so that destX and destY don't change? (Don't follow mouse or disappear)

PS: sorry for the miscellaneous information, this is supposed to build up to simple bullet physics.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const Please check this may be this sove your problem if it is related to const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there is some confusion about scoping, and there is probably a better way to think about this problem.

First let's look at what is going wrong, and talk through a few details to explain why.

- Just like variables (`let`, `var`), constants are always declared in a specific scope.
- Scopes are like containers for constants and variables. Scopes are private, that is they cannot be accessed from the outside. Scopes can be created and destroyed.
- When you declare a constant directly inside a function, the scope is the function itself (like `startX` inside `shoot`). (Note that if you declare a constant inside an `if` statement or other block, the scope is the block. That's not the case here, though.)
- Function scopes are created each time the function is called, and destroyed when the function is finished executing.
- Each time a function is called and its scope is created, all constants (and variables) are reinitialized with new values.
- A constant appearing in your code may have different values during different function calls. It is only constant during its lifetime, which in your case is a single given execution of the function.

This is why your constants aren't staying constant. You are calling `shoot()` repeatedly while the mouse is down, and so the constants are repeatedly being recreated and assigned new values.

With this information, hopefully you can see the problems with the current approach. As for a solution, let's think about what exactly is happening. `shoot()` is an action that should be triggered when the user issues a "shoot" command, such as a mouse click. The `draw()` function is a continuous event triggered to say "hey, update the screen". Putting the shoot action inside the draw event is kind of a mis-match of intentions and is the root of struggles like this.

Instead, let's introduce the idea of a `bullet` object. A bullet has an `x` and a `y` value. A bullet is created when the user shoots, and is given a specific x and y value at the moment of creation. None of this happens inside `draw`, it happens in another event listener such as `"click"`.

The job of `draw` is to check to see if there is an active bullet, and if there is one, draw it at the specified x and y coordinate. If there is no bullet, do nothing. (Of course you might need to draw other things as well, but that's unrelated to drawing the bullet).

Keeping object creation and object drawing separate makes it easier to have the kind of control you're looking for.

**Edit: Adding some code examples**

Here's what the code would look like to do exactly what you asked, using the bullet object idea above. The inline comments should explain each step.

```
// This is where we'll store an active bullet object.
// The `shoot()` function is responsible for setting this.
// `draw()` is responsible for rendering the bullet.
// Initially we'll set the value to `null` to explicitly
// indicate that there is no bullet.
let activeBullet = null;


// The purpose of `shoot()` is to create a bullet
// and make it available to be rendered.
function shoot(x, y) {
    // Create the bullet object.
    const newBullet = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        size: 25
    };

    // Set the active bullet to the new bullet. This will
    // cause any previously active bullet to disappear.
    activeBullet = newBullet;
}



// P5 functions
// ------------

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 650);
}


// Shoot when the player clicks.
function mousePressed() {
    shoot(mouseX, mouseY);
}


function draw() {
    // Always start with a blank canvas.
    clear();

    // If there is an active bullet, draw it!
    // (`null` is "falsy", objects are "truthy", so the
    // `if` statement will only run after the `activeBullet`
    // variable is assigned a bullet object.)
    if (activeBullet) {
        fill(0, 100, 200);
        rect(
            activeBullet.x - activeBullet.size / 2,
            activeBullet.y - activeBullet.size / 2,
            activeBullet.size,
            activeBullet.size
        );
    }
}
```

You also mentioned you wanted to build up to simple bullet physics. Just to show how the bullet object idea works nicely, here's a demo where you can click to shoot multiple bullets, they all move independently, and collide with a wall at which point they are removed. There's *a lot* more involved in building games, but hopefully it's an inspiring starting point :)

```
// Store canvas dimensions globally so we have easy access.
const canvasWidth = 1000;
const canvasHeight = 650;

// We'll add a "wall" object so we have something the bullets can
// collide with. This value is the X position of the wall.
const wallX = canvasWidth - 200;


// Instead of a single bullet, using an array can accommodate
// multiple bullets. It's empty to start, which means no bullets.
// We can also use `const` for this, because we won't ever assign
// a new value, we'll only modify the contents of the array.
const activeBullets = [];


function shoot(x, y) {
    // Create the bullet object.
    const newBullet = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        size: 25,
        speed: 4
    };

    // Instead of overwriting a single bullet variable, we'll push
    // the new bullet onto an array of bullets so multiple can exist.
    activeBullets.push(newBullet);
}



// P5 functions
// ------------

function setup() {
    createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}


// Shoot when the player clicks.
function mousePressed() {
    shoot(mouseX, mouseY);
}


function draw() {
    // Always start with a blank canvas.
    clear();

    // Draw our "wall".
    fill(50);
    rect(wallX, 0, 60, canvasHeight);

    // Set the fill color once, to use for all bullets. This doesn't
    // need to be set for each bullet.
    fill(0, 100, 200);

    // Loop through the array of bullets and draw each one, while also
    // checking for collisions with the wall so we can remove them. By
    // looping backwards, we can safely remove bullets from the array
    // without changing the index of the next bullet in line.
    for (let i=activeBullets.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        // Grab the current bullet we're operating on.
        const bullet = activeBullets[i];

        // Move the bullet horizontally.
        bullet.x += bullet.speed;

        // Check if the bullet has visually gone past the wall. This
        // means a collision.
        if (bullet.x + bullet.size / 2 > wallX) {
            // If the bullet has collided, remove it and don't draw it.
            activeBullets.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            // If the bullet hasn't collided, draw it.
            rect(
                bullet.x - bullet.size / 2,
                bullet.y - bullet.size / 2,
                bullet.size,
                bullet.size
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so now I know whats going on with my logic. How could I Make this happen? Until i hear back I will look into prototypes

Comment: I added some code examples to better illustrate how to implement the idea. FYI, most simple objects don't need anything set on their prototype, working with prototypes is an advanced feature of JS. As you can see, I used plain object literals for the bullets.

Comment: Sounds good It will need a lot of tweaking to go with my game concept but it satisfied all the details of the question I asked. SOLVED!

Comment: Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The `const` declaration exists only within the scope of `shoot`. So once the `shoot` function is finished executing, `startX startY destX destY`, being `const`, are deleted.

Possible fix:

```
var didShootAlready = false;
var startX, startY, destX, destY;

function shoot(/*params*/){
    if(!didShootAlready){
        didShootAlready = true;
        startX = x1;
        startY = y1;
        destX = x2;
        destY = y2;
    }
    //do the rest
}
```

Comment: Would this allow me to shoot multiple  times?

Comment: Yeah. I just gave an example to keep those variables constant. You'd do your other shooting code outside the if.

Comment: dont understand still... how would that work? how would it allow me to call that function as many times as id like? did shoot already would be true.

Comment: Sorry for not replying until now. didShootAlready is just the check to whether you should change those "const" coordinates or not. Do the rest of your shooting code where the comment is ("//do the rest") which is always executed, no matter whether didShootAlready is true